# Sql find Row with longest String and delete the Rest

Tags: sql-server, string

I am currently working on a table with approx. 7.5mio rows and 16 columns. One of the rows is an internal identifier (let's call it ID) we use at my university. Another column contains a string.

So, ID is NOT the unique index for a row, so it is possible that one identifier appears more than once in the table - the only difference between the two rows being the string.

I need to find all rows with ID and just keep the one with the longest string and deleting every other row from the original table. Unfortunately I am more of a SQL Novice, and I am really stuck at this point. So if anyone could help, this would be really nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this sample:

```
SELECT * INTO #sample FROM (VALUES
    (1, 'A'),
    (1,'Long A'),
    (2,'B'),
    (2,'Long B'),
    (2,'BB')
) T(ID,Txt)

DELETE S FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LEN(Txt) DESC) RN
    FROM #sample) S
WHERE RN!=1

SELECT * FROM #sample
```

**Results:**

```
ID  Txt
--  ------
1   Long A
2   Long B
```

Comment: Thank you Pawel! Just tried, and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible just in SQL, but the way I know how to do it would be a two-pass approach using application code - I assume you have an application you are writing.

The first pass would be something like:

`SELECT theid, count(*) AS num, MAX(LEN(thestring)) AS keepme FROM thetable WHERE num > 1 GROUP BY theid`

Then you'd loop through the results in whatever language you're using and delete anything with that ID except the one matching the string returned. The language I know is PHP, so I'll use it for my example, but the method would be the same in any language (for brevity, I'm skipping error checking, prepared statements, and such, and not testing - please use carefully):

```
$sql = 'SELECT theid, count(*) AS num, MAX(LEN(thestring)) AS keepme FROM thetable WHERE num > 1 GROUP BY theid';
$result = sqlsrv_query($resource, $sql);
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_object($result)) {
  $sql = 'DELETE FROM thetable WHERE theid = '.$row->theid.' AND NOT thestring = '.$row->keepme;
  $result = sqlsrv_query($resource, $sql);
}
```

You didn't say what you would want to do if two strings are the same length, so this solution does not deal with that at all - I'm assuming that each ID will only have one longest string.

Comment: Yes, it is a uni project. I am a mathematician and this is just a first step to get the data. I am working with R and a c++ lib that we develop at the moment. Using R would have used 28 days of cpu time - at least with my implementation. So it was crucial to try a sql query that could work a lot faster on the server the dbms is installed on. If you are interested I could outline my implementation in R but its rather straightforward as I am still getting used to it. I am more of a c++/boost guy